# Handling Date and Time in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, datetime

I want to persist both Date and Time from a Datepicker and a Timepicker in a Spring MVC application. I was able to persist either the Date, or the Time only. Not them together.

Here is a snap into my model class:

```
 @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
 private Date date;
 @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "HH:mm:ss")
 private Date time;



public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

 public Date getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(Date time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
```

While persisting using Hibernate with this model class I can only get either Date or, Time persisted. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried these @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.NONE)?

DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME    : 2011-07-11T21:28:59.564+01:00

DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE         : 2011-07-11

DateTimeFormat.ISO.TIME         : 21:37:21.394+01:00

DateTimeFormat.ISO.NONE         : 7/11/11 9:44 PM

Comment: I have separate Date picker and Time Picker in my view, and also they are separate columns in the database table. Using DateTimeFormat.ISO.NONE I can only put this two things together right? But what should I do if I want to persist them separately in two separate columns I have in my database?

Comment: Can you paste your view and controller code so i have some clarity about your problem?